# Why is nicotine gum so expensive?

Tags: nicotine

If one can purchase nicotine liquid for e-cigarettes at a concentration of 100mg/ml for roughly 130$ a liter, why is nicotine gum so expensive in the US and Canada?

Are there regulations on the sale of nicotine gum?  Are their formulation costs associated with the production of nicotine gum?

Comment: What the market will bear.

Comment: What @CareyGregory said, basically the answer to the question "Why does X medication cost so much?!" is related to how much the company thinks people will pay for it.  Want to make a fortune? Develop a medication, patent the formula so no one else can sell it, then charge any exorbitant amount you want until the patent runs out and other companies can make a generic version.  Even if it's a life-saving medication/formulation, there's no one regulating prices - at least not in the USA.  Plenty of examples in the last couple of years...